# Generate preview thumbnail (sample) using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails, thumbnail-generator

I tried to google for a way to generate preview thumbnail (sample) like [MPC-HC does](https://youtu.be/QRx0AEr6pe4):
[image: MPC_HC_Thumbnails.jpg]

As you can see, the thumbnail should have multiple frames and show the time of the frame, extra info of the video like Duration, Name, Size, Resolution should be a plus but not required. I don't want [single frame thumbnail](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video).

Reasons I want to find a way to do this with ffmpeg instead of just install MPC:

- I already have VLC to play every video there is. I only install a new program if I have no other choice, and I prefer portable programs.
- I prefer the way ffmpeg does stuff: command line. So #1: I can automate the process, #2: no one can look what video I'm working with.
- I want to know if ffmpeg can do this.

Comment: Good news that MPC also have portable version: https://mpc-hc.org/downloads/

Comment: There is a request for MPC command line Generate Thumbnail about 9 years ago: https://trac.mpc-hc.org/ticket/639 , but seem like it's still not available yet.

Comment: Also, In MPC, to see all available commands go to Help -> Command Line Switches

Answer (score -1):

```
const NodeTerminal = require("child_process").exec;

const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

//mini video

NodeTerminal(
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 320x240 -vf "select='between(t,5,7)+between(t,23,25)+between(t,46,49)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -af "aselect='between(t,5,7)+between(t,23,25)+between(t,46,49)',asetpts=N/SR/TB" -an ${uuidv4()}.mp4`
);

//image thumbnails

NodeTerminal(
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -fps_mode vfr -vf "select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,2)',scale=160:90,tile=7x7" ${uuidv4()}.jpg`
);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code rather than posting only code.

Comment: What is this? A NodeJS program?